# How to get key to decrypt msgstore.db.crypt12 database in Whatsapp in non-root Android?

Tags: backup, whatsapp-messenger, xiaomi-pocophone-f1

I want to decrypt msgstore.db.crypt12 in my non-rooted android phone. I tried multiple steps using adb but nothing worked

```
run-as com.whatsapp
adb backup com.whatsapp
```

How can I do so? Is there any way to backup full android to a file on laptop and extract key from it? Please suggest.

Comment: https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2770982&page=33